# Webcam Video Conference plugin wordpress,Net connection.connect failed

Tags: wordpress, plugins, webcam, video-conferencing

I am using(Webcam Video Conference by VideoWhisper.com). This plugin in my localhost before hosting live. 
After configuring plugin and given shortcode in a page while i am running showing  `NetConnection.Connect.Failed`

I tried to rectify that by installing rtmp, red5 and also copy and paste vc_php files that i downloaded into plugin file.

Still showing the same error.

```
RTMP Address :rtmp://localhost/videowhisper
```

I have given this as rtmp address, because i am doing this in local system.

```
RTMFP Address:rtmfp://stratus.adobe.com/(Adobe cirrus key that i got)/
```

Please help anyone who know how to run this plugin properly without any errors.